# Problems with ide-helper laravel: Factory not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am running `ide-helper` in my `Laravel Framework 8.33.1` project. To generate the model facade declarations (command: `php artisan ide-helper:models`) I am getting this error:

```
Exception: Class 'Database\Factories\XXXFactory' not found
Could not analyze class App\Models\XXX.
```

Do I need a factory for each model or why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is a known bug with ide-helper 2.9.1, see here:

[Github Issue 1188 ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/1188)

How I solved it:
I removed

```
use HasFactory
```

from all models which do not have an according factory class implemented.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but I'm not sure if this is a bug. If the model has no factory, it shouldn't implement the HasFactory trait.

Answer (score 1):

In your Ide-helper config file, set 'include_factory_builders' to false

config/ide-helper.php

```
'include_factory_builders' => false,
```

Comment: @F_Schmidt then try `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: This didn't make any difference. Still getting the same error.